# Inverse of a Particular $n\times n$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ where the elements are defined as $a(i,i)=2 ,a(i+1,i)=a(i,i+1)=-1$ for all $i=1 \ldots n-1$.Also a(i,j)=0 otherwise.

Find the inverse of the matrix.

Is there any elegant way to find the inverse completely?

Comment: Please make sure I edited your question properly.

Comment: Do you intend the other elements to be all $0$?

Comment: Also since there's no index $n+1$, you want $a(i+1,i) = a(i,i+1) = -1$ for $i = 1 \ldots n-1$, not $1 \ldots n$.

Comment: I have just edited it..

Answer (score 1):

For your particular $A$, I think the easiest way to find its inverse is by simple inspection. Computer experiments suggest that the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^{-1}$ should be $\frac{1}{n+1}(n+1-\max(i,j))\min(i,j)$, and you can check whether this is indeed correct.

More generally, as the other answer points out, your $A$ is a special case of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix and explicit formula for its inverse is known. Actually, your $A$ is nicer -- it is a symmetric tridiagonal **Toeplitz** matrix. Inverses of matrices of this class can be expressed in terms of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind. See, e.g. corollary 4.2 of

> C.M. da Fonseca and J. Petronilho,
>   [*Explicit inverses of some tridiagonal matrices*](https://estudogeral.sib.uc.pt/bitstream/10316/4651/1/filedfd7b2e235a64370a841fec4c14dc690.pdf),
>   Linear Algebra and its Applications, 325(2001): 7-21.

Answer (score 0):

See:

G.Y.Hu and R.F.O’Connell, Analytical inversion of symmetric tridiagonal matrices. J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. {\bf 29}(1996), pp.1511–1513.