# How to find the inverse of a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Let $a, b>0$, and the matrix $A_{n \times n}$ and such
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&0&\cdots&0&0\\
b&a&b&\cdots&0&0\\
0&b&a&\cdots&0&0\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&b&a&b\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&b&a
\end{bmatrix}$$
Find the inverse $A^{-1}$.

---

My idea: $$A^{-1}=\dfrac{A^{*}}{|A|}$$
and let $|A|=D_{n}$, then we have
$$D_{n}=aD_{n-1}-b^2D_{n-2}$$
so
$$D_{n}=\begin{cases}
(n+1)\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)^n,a^2=4b^2\\
\dfrac{(a+\sqrt{a^2-4b^2})^{n+1}-(a-\sqrt{a^2-4b^2})^{n+1}}{2^{n-1}\sqrt{a^2-4b^2}}&a^2\neq 4b^2
\end{cases}$$
and then I fell very ugly, do you have other methods?
Thank you

Comment: Is it a shifting matrix? If it is there might be some cool trick to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&0&\cdots&0&0\\
b&a&b&\cdots&0&0\\
0&b&a&\cdots&0&0\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&b&a&b\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&b&a
\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}
1&b/a&0&\cdots&0&0\\
b/a&1&b/a&\cdots&0&0\\
0&b/a&1&\cdots&0&0\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&b/a&1&b/a\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&b/a&1
\end{bmatrix} =: aX.$$

So, $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{a} X^{-1}$.

To find $X^{-1}$, apply [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179900/78926). You can also find some references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478732/78926).

In case you want to search further, your matrix is [tridiagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) (a special kind of [band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix)) [Toeplitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix.